# Use parallelism to solve a recursive function with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

I'm trying to optimize a process which is to calculate all possible combinations of players to form partitions. To understand my problem, I use the following example. For exampe we have a set of players `N = {1,2,3,4,5}`
, this players are regrouped like this `{1,2},{3,4},{5}`. It means palyer 1 will play with player 2 as a single player, and so one. Each group of players has a set of strategies or choices. Each player chooses the group to which he wants to belong, for example:
the group `{1,2}` has these possibilites `{{1,2};{1,2,3,4}}`; i.e the players {1,2} either they choose to stay together or to join the group{3,4}.
the same explanation for the rest of players:

```
{3,4}=>{{3,4};{3,4,5};{1,2,3,4}}
{5}=>{{5};{3,4,5}}
```

Now, the group of players choosing the same strategy will form a new group (coalition). For example, group`{1,2}` chose the strategy `{1,2,3,4}` ;ie. the players {1,2} want to form a new group with players{3,4}. Players {3,4} choose the strategy `{3,4,5}`, player`{5}` choose the strategy `{3,4,5}`. The players have chosen the same strategy will be grouped together to form in the final a partition of players like this:{1,2},{3,4,5}; players 3,4,5 have choosen the same strategy, so they grouped together, players {1,2} choose adifferent strategy so theu stay alone. We do the same with all possible combinations of players' strategies to obtain all possible partitions of players which have the cardinality = K. In the final, I must choose the optimal partition of players. In the previous example: I must generate only the partitions having the cardinality = 2: 
    |{1,2,3,4},{5}|=2
    |{1,2}{3,4,5}|=3
this partitions is not admissibles: `|{1,2}{3,4}{5}|=3`
I have programed this process as a recursive function to get all admissibles partitions of players. Another problem here my function generate all possible partitions and I get only the admissibles which takes many times!!

Now my question is if it is possible to use parallilism in java to compute all admissible partitions of players, especially when we have many players and so many partitions. What I must do to accelerate the execution of a large problem ?

```
 import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Comparator;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 import java.util.stream.Stream;
 public class Test {
 @SafeVarargs
 static <T> Set<T> set(T ... elems) {
  return new HashSet<T>(asList(elems));
 }
 static <T> List<Set<Set<T>>> calcPartitions(List<T> teams, Map<T,    List<Set<T>>> team2Strategies, int k, boolean doParallel) {
if(k == 0) {
  if(teams.isEmpty()) return asList(new HashSet<>());
  else return new ArrayList<>();
} else if(teams.isEmpty()) {
  return new ArrayList<>();
}

Set<T> teamsSet = new HashSet<>(teams);

T team = teams.get(0);
Stream<Set<T>> strategies = 
  (doParallel ? team2Strategies.get(team).parallelStream() : team2Strategies.get(team).stream())
    .filter(strategy ->
      strategy.stream().allMatch(team2 ->
        teamsSet.contains(team2) && team2Strategies.get(team2).contains(strategy)));
  return strategies.flatMap(strategy -> {
    List<T> newTeams = new ArrayList<>(teams);
    newTeams.removeAll(strategy);
    List<Set<Set<T>>> restPartitions = calcPartitions(newTeams, team2Strategies, k - 1, false);
    for(Set<Set<T>> partition: restPartitions) {
      partition.add(strategy);
    }
    return restPartitions.stream();
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Set<Integer>> teams = asList(set(0,1,2), set(3,4), set(5),set(6,7,8),set(9,10,11),set(12,13,14));

Map<Set<Integer>, List<Set<Set<Integer>>>> team2Strategies = new HashMap<>();

team2Strategies.put(set(0,1,2), asList(set(set(0,1, 2)),
                                     set(set(0,1, 2), set(3, 4))));
team2Strategies.put(set(3,4), asList(set(set(3, 4), set(5)),
                                     set(set(0,1, 2), set(3, 4))));
team2Strategies.put(set(5), asList(set(set(5)),
                                   set(set(3, 4), set(5)),set(set(5),set(6,7,8)),set(set(5),set(6,7,8),set(9,10,11),set(12,13,14))));


team2Strategies.put(set(6,7,8), asList(set(set(6,7,8)),
        set(set(6, 7,8), set(5)),set(set(5),set(6,7,8),set(9,10,11),set(12,13,14))));

team2Strategies.put(set(9,10,11), asList(set(set(9,10,11)),
        set(set(9, 10,11), set(12,13,14)),set(set(5),set(6,7,8),set(9,10,11),set(12,13,14))));

team2Strategies.put(set(12,13,14), asList(set(set(12,13,14)),
        set(set(12, 13,14), set(9,10,11)),set(set(5),set(6,7,8),set(9,10,11),set(12,13,14))));
List<Set<Set<Set<Integer>>>> partitions = calcPartitions(teams,   team2Strategies, 3, true);

  Comparator<List<Integer>> intListComparator = (a, b) -> {
  int i = 0;
  while(i < a.size() && i < b.size()) {
    if(a.get(i) > b.get(i)) return 1;
    else if(a.get(i) < b.get(i)) return -1;
    i++;
  }
  return a.size() - b.size();
};

//in "partitions" a strategy was a Set<Set<Integer>>
//in "partitionsList" however a strategy is a List<Integer>
List<List<List<Integer>>> partitionsList =
  partitions.stream().map(partition ->
    partition.stream().map(strategy ->
      strategy.stream().flatMap(Set::stream)
                       .sorted()
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .sorted(intListComparator).collect(Collectors.toList()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(partitionsList);

System.out.println(
  partitionsList.stream().map(partition ->
    partition.stream().map(strategy ->
      strategy.stream().map(i -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining()))
  .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
 }
}
```

Comment: It is slow because you manipulate too much objects. I suggest you replace |{1,2,3,4},{5}| by a String s= "1_2_3_4;5" then use split("_") and split(";"). By the way, multithreading won't solve your problem.

Comment: Actually string operations may even be slower than lookups in an ArrayList, which has constant access time (just like a normal array)

Comment: It is possible to rewrite this function in a non recursive way in order to use parallelism?!

Comment: is it possible to use jcuda in order to accelerate the calcul of all partitions, especially when we have many players and strategies ?!

Answer (score 0):

The Stream class in Java 8 is able to automatically execute operations in parallel where possible.
Of course for that to work it's important that inside the code that might be run in parallel all operations must be thread safe. The easiest way to achieve that is to avoid any modifications of variables or collections.
Here is a solution that uses streams. It also only goes through each possible partition once and should be fairly efficient.
I represented each partition as a list of strategies. Each strategy is a list of teams. Each team in turn is also a list.
That means the list of teams might look like this:
`[[1,2], [3,4], [5]]`
a strategy could look like this
`[[3,4], [5]]` (meaning team `[3,4]` and team `[5]` pair up).
And a partition might look like this
`[[[1,2]], [[3,4], [5]]]` which is equal to `{1,2}{3,4,5}`

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
  static <T> List<List<List<T>>> calcPartitions(List<T> teams, Map<T, List<List<T>>> team2Strategies, int k, boolean doParallel) {
    if(k == 0) {
      if(teams.isEmpty()) return asList(new ArrayList<>());
      else return new ArrayList<>();
    } else if(teams.isEmpty()) {
      return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    T team = teams.get(0);
    Stream<List<T>> strategies = 
      (doParallel ? team2Strategies.get(team).parallelStream() : team2Strategies.get(team).stream())
        .filter(strategy ->
          strategy.stream().allMatch(team2 ->
            teams.contains(team2) && team2Strategies.get(team2).contains(strategy)));
      return strategies.flatMap(strategy -> {
        List<T> newTeams = new ArrayList<>(teams);
        newTeams.removeAll(strategy);
        List<List<List<T>>> restPartitions = calcPartitions(newTeams, team2Strategies, k - 1, false);
        for(List<List<T>> partition: restPartitions) {
          partition.add(0, strategy);
        }
        return restPartitions.stream();
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> teams = asList(asList(1,2), asList(3,4), asList(5));

    Map<List<Integer>, List<List<List<Integer>>>> team2Strategies = new HashMap<>();

    team2Strategies.put(asList(1,2), asList(asList(asList(1, 2)),
                                            asList(asList(1, 2), asList(3, 4))));
    team2Strategies.put(asList(3,4), asList(asList(asList(3, 4)),
                                            asList(asList(3, 4), asList(5)),
                                            asList(asList(1, 2), asList(3, 4))));
    team2Strategies.put(asList(5), asList(asList(asList(5)),
                                          asList(asList(3, 4), asList(5))));

    List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> partitions = calcPartitions(teams, team2Strategies, 2, true);

    System.out.println(
      partitions.stream().map(partition ->
        partition.stream().map(strategy ->
          strategy.stream().map(team ->
            team.stream().map(i -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
          .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}")))
        .collect(Collectors.joining()))
      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
  }
}
```

The output of this program is

```
{1, 2}{3, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 4}{5}
```

**edit:**

I have to represent each team individually for this strategy to work. But you can improve it by using sets instead of lists. That way `[[3,4],[5]]` will be equal to `[[5],[3,4]]`. Sets should also make the whole program faster. After the solutions are found you can then convert that to a nicer form i.e. convert `[[3,4],[5]]` into `[3,4,5]` and also sort the numbers while you're at it.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
  @SafeVarargs
  static <T> Set<T> set(T ... elems) {
    return new HashSet<T>(asList(elems));
  }

  static <T> List<Set<Set<T>>> calcPartitions(List<T> teams, Map<T, List<Set<T>>> team2Strategies, int k, boolean doParallel) {
    if(k == 0) {
      if(teams.isEmpty()) return asList(new HashSet<>());
      else return new ArrayList<>();
    } else if(teams.isEmpty()) {
      return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    Set<T> teamsSet = new HashSet<>(teams);

    T team = teams.get(0);
    Stream<Set<T>> strategies = 
      (doParallel ? team2Strategies.get(team).parallelStream() : team2Strategies.get(team).stream())
        .filter(strategy ->
          strategy.stream().allMatch(team2 ->
            teamsSet.contains(team2) && team2Strategies.get(team2).contains(strategy)));
      return strategies.flatMap(strategy -> {
        List<T> newTeams = new ArrayList<>(teams);
        newTeams.removeAll(strategy);
        List<Set<Set<T>>> restPartitions = calcPartitions(newTeams, team2Strategies, k - 1, false);
        for(Set<Set<T>> partition: restPartitions) {
          partition.add(strategy);
        }
        return restPartitions.stream();
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  static List<Set<Integer>> teams = new ArrayList<>();
  static Map<Set<Integer>, List<Set<Set<Integer>>>> team2Strategies = new HashMap<>();

  private static Set<Integer> toSet(String string) {
    return Stream.of(string.split(" ")).map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.trim())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }

  @SafeVarargs
  private static void defineTeams(List<String> ... definitions) {
    for(List<String> def: definitions) {
      teams.add(toSet(def.get(0)));
    }

    for(List<String> def: definitions) {
      Set<Integer> team = toSet(def.get(0));
      Stream<Set<Integer>> strategies = def.stream().skip(1).map(s -> toSet(s));
      List<Set<Set<Integer>>> startegiesList =
        strategies.map(strat -> teams.stream().filter(strat::containsAll).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
      team2Strategies.put(team, startegiesList);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    defineTeams(asList("0 1 2", "0 1 2", "0 1 2 3 4"),
                asList("3 4", "3 4 5", "0 1 2 3 4"),
                asList("5", "5", "3 4 5", "5 6 7 8", "5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14"),
                asList("6 7 8", "6 7 8", "5 6 7 8", "5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14"),             
                asList("9 10 11", "9 10 11", "9 10 11 12 13 14", "5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14"),
                asList("12 13 14", "12 13 14", "9 10 11 12 13 14", "5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14"));

    System.out.println("teams = "+ teams);
    System.out.println("team trategies = " + team2Strategies);
    System.out.println();

    List<Set<Set<Set<Integer>>>> partitions = calcPartitions(teams, team2Strategies, 3, true);

    Comparator<List<Integer>> intListComparator = (a, b) -> {
      int i = 0;
      while(i < a.size() && i < b.size()) {
        if(a.get(i) > b.get(i)) return 1;
        else if(a.get(i) < b.get(i)) return -1;
        i++;
      }
      return a.size() - b.size();
    };

    System.out.println(partitions);

    //in "partitions" a strategy was a Set<Set<Integer>>
    //in "partitionsList" however a strategy is a List<Integer>
    List<List<List<Integer>>> partitionsList =
      partitions.stream().map(partition ->
        partition.stream().map(strategy ->
          strategy.stream().flatMap(Set::stream)
                           .sorted()
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .sorted(intListComparator).collect(Collectors.toList()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(partitionsList);

    System.out.println(
      partitionsList.stream().map(partition ->
        partition.stream().map(strategy ->
          strategy.stream().map(i -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}")))
        .collect(Collectors.joining()))
      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. But when I executing your program I have these errors: ` Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: partition cannot be resolved to a variable Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
 partition cannot be resolved
 strategy cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
 strategy cannot be resolved
 team cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
 team cannot be resolved
 i cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
 i cannot be resolved

Comment: "Unresolved compilation problems" means there is something wrong with javac. Try removing java completely and then reinstall the latest JDK.

Comment: I haven't understand what is the problem, I put jre 1.8 as external jar

Comment: What version of javac do you use?

Comment: I use java 6, but to execute you program I have installed java 8.

Comment: I use Java 1.8.0_45 and the code compiles fine. No error messages.

Comment: ok, I will  remove java completely and then reinstall the latest JDK

Comment: I have installed java 8, but I have the same problems. It demands to configure build path, I have only jre 1.8 in my machine. The method asList(int, int) is undefined for the type Test,Syntax error on token "-", -- expected,partition cannot be resolved,strategy cannot be resolved to a variable, .... What is the problem here ?

Comment: Now, it works the problem is in eclipse. Now, I want that strategies are like this [3,4,5] not like you are represented them as[[3,4],[5]]. Because, after I have another problem with your representation which is the order of plaayers. For example: strategy [[3,4],[5]] is equal to [[5],[3,4]] but in your program is not, and in order to simplify represntation when I have more players and many strategies. I have changed the code but it doesn't work, what is the problem here ?!

Comment: I added an improved solution to my answer. It should hopefully work correctly now.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but your code doesn't generate all possible permutations of a specific K. Show the example in my edited code. The code must generate 6 permutations of cardinality equal to 3, but it displays only one permutation ?!

Comment: I edited my code to make it easier to define the teams and strategies. I tried out your example and it does indeed only output one solution: `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}{5, 6, 7, 8}{9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}`. What other solutions did you expect it to find? It doesn't look like there are any other. Not if the number of partitions has to be exactly 3.

Comment: Thank you for your  help. There are others permutations with cardinality equal to 3. For example; players{0,1,2} choose strategy {0,1,2,3,4}, players {3,4}=>{3,4,5}, player {5}=>{3,4,5}, players{6,4,8}=>{5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}, players{9,10,11}=>{5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}, players{12,13,14}=>{5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}. So players {0,1,2} stay alone they have chosen a different strategy from others. players {3,4,5} must be grouped together thet chosen the same strategy. the same explnation with players{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}.So the partition is;{0,1,2}{3,4,5}{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}.

Comment: Wait, does that mean all sub-strategies of a strategy are also valid? So if {6,7,8} chooses strategy {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14} that means that {5,6,7,8}, {6,7,8,9,10,11},{6,7,8,12,13,14}, {5,6,7,8,9,10,11}, {5,6,7,8,12,13,14} and {6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14} are automatically also all valid strategies?

Comment: No, it isn't,  the strategy for players {6,7,8} is{5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14} and not {6,7,8,12,1,13,14},....The set of strategis is as defined first, we don't take all possible subsets of strategies. which we interest here is that the palyers who choose the same strategy will be grouped togetehr. we can say that the strategy is shown as a label, so the players having chosen the same label regrouped togheter.

Comment: ok, let's say we use letters as labels. Strategy A = {0,1,2,3,4}, B = {6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}, C = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}, etc.  Then {6,7,8} chooses strategy C, {9,10,11} and {12,13,14} also choose C. Since they all choose the same strategy they can be grouped together. That's fine but what happens if {6,7,8} chooses C but {9,10,11} and {12,13,14} choose B? Can they still be grouped together to form {6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}?

Comment: In this case, players {6,7,8} stay togather and players {9,10,11,12,13,14} form a new group. for example palyers {0,1,2} and {3,4}choose  A , so they regrouped together; player 5 choose the startegy {5,6,7,8}; so it stays alone because it chooses a different strategy from others. So the partition here is:{0,1,2,3,4}{5}{6,7,8}{9,10,11,12,13,14}.

Comment: Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Ok, let's try this again. So each team can be grouped  together only with teams that have choosen the exact same strategy. But the group they form can be a sub set of that strategy? If {9,10,11} and {12,13,14} both choose strategy {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}, they can be grouped together into {9,10,11,12,13,14} which is a subset of {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}?

Comment: Yes, because players have choosen the strategy where they are members, or which they want to belong. And the memebrs of the chosen strategy who chose a different strategy rest alone or form a new group if they have chosen the same strategy.

Comment: It is possible to resolve this function without recursivity; i.e. means can I use a sequential function to generate all possible partitions ?!